MS Defender Recomendation-: Managed identity should be used in web apps
We have a situation with a PAAS application where in Azure Advisor it is asking us to enable Managed identity should be used in web apps and Function APP . Our concern is that if I specifically change this to be Managed indentiese then will it break something? The company is not willing to help us unless we pay for it even though this is a simple question for them to answer that either something will break or nothing will break. But, they want to charge us to provide that answer.
There is no info on their website about .Currently web app used Connection string for connecting DB and using encryted Credential So we dont want to change Code . So, how can we address this. If we enable  System Identity ON  on wepservice /func app  and it  will breaks  application or not  ?? wait for them to get back.

Can you please provide more details about the issue.


Azure Advisor it is asking us to enable Managed identity should be used in web apps

For few apps (mainly .NET), Whenever you deploy web App to Azure App Service, by default System Identity is Enabled.

Whereas Apps created with Python/Django/PHP/Node runtime stack will have System Identity disabled.



When you enable System Identity for a Web App, a new App with App Service name,Service Principal will be registered under Enterprise Application in Microsoft Entra ID.



You can check it in Microsoft Entra ID(Azure AD) =>Enterprise applications =>All applications(remove the filter).



If we enable System Identity ON on wepservice /func app and it will breaks application or not ??


If you are using any of the resources like KeyVault/Storage/SQL, you need to add permissions to access.



If you have configured any of the above resources and not assigned the role/permission, your app will break and may not work as expected.

Refer Managed identities - Azure App Service which explains the same.

If your app is simple and plain, even if you enable Identity without any role assignments, app works without any issues.

Check the Activity log, you can see only the App is updated.




As you mentioned you are connecting to DB, you need to provide required roles to that resource.


Our application connect SQL with connection string, connects Azure Storage  with storage Connection string and acquire Keyvault key with  rest API using access key client ID .. (without using managed ID )
so I have to confirm if I enabled to System Identity ON on the dot net app ( as my app was 5 years only  , system identity was not set by default .) Can the application work without break?
Your clarification will be greatly appreciated.

As I have already mentioned, you need to give permissions to access your DB and storage account.

If my DB /storage connect with Connection string , Y my app need permission  after System Identity ON ..

AFAIK,the existing configuration(connection string) for the app will continue without any break.But for any new configuration, your app  needs to assign specific roles.
